# Why useEffect isn't changing the paragraph?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying React useEffect hook and trying to use it in a simple example. I want to have the paragraph *showing modal* as an effect that happens ONLY when the modal is open, and disappears when the modal is closed.

So I have only the View component in index.js, and that's the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal.js';

const View = () => {
    let [showModal, setModal] = React.useState(false)
        
    React.useEffect(() => {        
        document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'Showing modal'
        
        return () => {
            document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = ''
        }
    }, [showModal])

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={() => {setModal(!showModal)}}>
                Show modal
            </button>

            <Modal showModal={showModal} setModal={setModal}/>
        
            <p id="alerta" ></p>
        </>
    )
}

export default View;
```

Modal.js looks like this

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = (props) => {
    if(props.showModal){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Showing modal</h1>
                <button onClick={() => props.setModal(false)}>Close</button>
            </div>
        )
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

As explained in the documentation, my effect returns a function that should run when the effect is cleaned, that's when the modal is closed. I also have specified that I want to run the effect only when something changes in my showModal state.

If I insert a *console.log(showModal)* inside my effect function, I'll see its value changing when the modal is shown or when it's closed, but the problem is, the paragraph is ALWAYS there.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the effect hook runs, it will populate the paragraph:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'Showing modal'

    return () => {
        document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = ''
    }
}, [showModal])
```

Every render, if `showModal` changes, no matter what it changes to:

- The cleanup from the prior render will run, clearing the content
- The effect for the new render will run, populating the content

So it will always look populated.

The right way to do this would be to put the toggling logic into the JSX and use state instead of DOM methods:

```js
const View = () => {
    let [showModal, setModal] = React.useState(false)
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={() => {setModal(!showModal)}}>
                Show modal
            </button>

            <div style={{ display: showModal ? 'block' : 'none' }}>modal here...</div>
        
            <p id="alerta">{showModal ? 'Showing modal' : ''}</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<View />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```